# Azure Community gallery not listed publicly

Tags: azure

I opted in to the Azure Community Gallery PREVIEW feature and created a shared community gallery:

```
az sig create --resource-group Public --gallery-name PublicGallery --permissions Groups --publisher-uri https://example.com --publisher-email contact@example.com --eula 1 --public-name-prefix 1
az sig share enable-community --gallery-name PublicGallery --resource-group Public
```

In the Azure web portal, I can see the gallery is created under the correct resource group with the following parameters:

```
Sharing method: Community
Sharing status: Shared
```

However, when I list all public community galleries under this region using the CLI, it doesn't show it:

```bash
az sig list-community
```

Getting it by name results in an error

```bash
az sig show-community --location germanywestcentral --public-gallery-name public1-HIDDEN
(NotFound) please check if the gallery name 'public1-HIDDEN' is valid and the gallery exists in 'GermanyWestCentral' region.
Code: NotFound
Message: please check if the gallery name 'public1-HIDDEN' is valid and the gallery exists in 'GermanyWestCentral' region.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure CLI command, ***Add permissions as community instead of group*** like below:-

```bash
az sig create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --gallery-name MyGallery123 --permissions Community --publisher-uri www.contoso.com --publisher-email contoso@gmail.com --eula 1 --public-name-prefix 3
```

Refer this **Note** from MS Document below:-

> Note- During the preview, the gallery must be created as a community
> gallery (for CLI, this means using the
> `--permissions community`
> parameter) you currently can't migrate a regular gallery to a
> community gallery.

**Note Reference:-** [Share Azure Compute Gallery resources with a community gallery - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/share-gallery-community?tabs=cli)

Also, Check the **Limitations** of Azure Compute Community gallery as the **feature is still in preview:-**

[Share Azure Compute Gallery resources with a community gallery - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/share-gallery-community?tabs=cli#limitations-for-images-shared-to-the-community)

After you change permissions to community try running the command below:-

```bash
az sig list-community --location germanywestcentral
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

After creating and sharing the gallery with the `--permissions community` parameter, it is still not listed. I can't see any difference. Also checked the community gallery Limitations, didn't find anything that would be an issue.

Comment: As azure shared community gallery service is still in preview, Some features might not be generally available, You can raise a Feedback here to get the solution or alternative:-https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/ec2f1827-be25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c